# Angular observable array, populated by an http request and manually added data

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to get my head around observables in Angular 6, but I'm new to anything more recent than AngularJS and seriously struggling right now. I think I've gone through every tutorial I can find and searched extensively here, so hopefully I'm not missing anything, but happy to take friendly pointers...

What I'm trying to do is this:

1. GET request to a backend API, returns a JSON array of **items**, and display that array in a component as a data list
2. Allow a second component to POST new **item**s to the backend, and also add that **item** to the list of **items** above

I'm guessing I'm describing an observable, because #1 needs to be asynchronous, but all the examples I've seen seem to only deal with one of the two steps, not both together. What am I missing?

Comment: It's not really all that different from the Angular JS HTTP library except instead of returning a promise, the Angular HTTP library returns an Observable. At a very basic level, where you would call `.then` on the promise, you would call `.subscribe` on the Observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@1: GET request to a backend API, returns a JSON array of items, and display that array in a component as a data list

let's call this one ComponentA:

```
export class ComponentA {        
    arrayOfItems:Type[];
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

    getDataFromAPI():Observable<Type[]> {
        this.http.get<Type[]>('api-get-url')
            .subscribe(
                (items) => {
                    //print them if you want;console.log('response from the api', items);
                    this.arrayOfItems = items;
                }
            )
    }
}
```

@2.1: Allow a second component to POST new items to the backend (omitted a part of the question on purpose)

```
export class ComponentB {  
    // let's assume this array is already populated
    // via you 2-way bindings or whatever means 
    newItems:Type[];
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

    postDataToAPI():Observable<any> {
        this.http.post('api-post-url', this.newItem)
            .subscribe(
                response => console.log('response from the api', response);
            )
    }
}
```

@2.2 and also add that item to the list of items above

Everything ^ was straightforward, but now you gotta stop and think: I have something 'here' and something 'there'. How can I ... connect them? Ha! Connect! So  I need some sort of mechanism to connect the 2 components. What do you do? You use a service! But a service whose purpose is to store a shared data set. You can call it DataStoreService.

Let's (re)write some code:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataStoreService() {
    items:Type[] = [];
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

    getDataFromTheAPI():Observable<Type[]> {
            this.http.get<Type[]>('api-get-url')
                .subscribe(items => this.items = items)
    }

    postDataToTheAPI(itemToAdd:Type):Observable<any> {
            this.http.post('api-post-url', itemsToAdd)
                .subscribe(
                    (response) => {
                        // check if all is good, and add it to the 'items' array
                        addItem(itemToAdd);
                    }
            }
        )
    }

    getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    addItem(item:Type) {
        this.items.push(item);
    }
}
```

Now, your Component A changes to:

```
export class ComponentA implements OnInit{
    constructor(private dataStoreService: DataStoreService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataStoreService.getDataFromTheAPI(); 
        // ^ will request the data from the API and store it 
        // inside the service
    }

    // and here you get a reference to that data
    get itemsReferenceFromService() {
        return this.jobsStoreService.getJobsArray();
    }
}
```

And ComponentB to:

```
export class ComponentB {
    newItem:Type;
    constructor(private dataStoreService: DataStoreService) {}

    // when you do this, if successful, addItem method
    // will also be called that will 'and also add that item to the list of items above'; as componentA only has a reference to the data in 
    // the service, the new item will be displayed it it
    this.dataStoreService.postDataToTheAPI(newItem);
}
```

Hope this answers your question. If you have any other doubts, say it loud. Info like urls were omitted.

A further improvement is to have another service that **only** handles the API calls, and keep the DataService **clean** just for storing purposes. That will ease **testing**.

Be aware that the lifespan of any Service/Component in angular is up untill the end user refreshed the page. The service described is not a persistence mechanism.

Comment: oh, and you can use 'itemsReferenceFromService' in your ComponentA to  display the data. without the (), just bind it to 'itemsReferenceFromService'

Comment: @Rollo, if the answer answers your question, make sure to mark it as accepted by clicking on the Tick icon at its top left

Comment: This answer was perfect and gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for deciphering what I was asking so expertly and so quickly!

Turns out I do need to read up on 2-way data binding, but that should be less of a headache...

Comment: Great! Always happy to help a fellow Angularian!

Comment: What should getDataFromTheAPI() and postDataToTheAPI() be returning? I initially got an error because they weren't returning anything, so I tried changing to 
`    getDataFromTheAPI():Observable<Type[]> {
            return this.http.get<Type[]>('api-get-url')
                .subscribe(items => this.items = items)
    }
`
 and 
`
    getDataFromTheAPI():Observable<Type[]> {
            this.http.get<Type[]>('api-get-url')
                .subscribe(items => this.items = items)
            return this.items;
    }
`
but neither seemed to work?

Sorry for the formatting...

Answer (score 0):

That because it is two different things.

The first is an request that you are expecting data from. so you **subscribe** to it.

```
$newsletter = NewYorkTimesService.getData(); // this does some http stuff.
$newsletter.subscribe(newspaper => readData(newpaper) /*or whatever you want to do with json */ );
```

The second is a total different call (and different observable) to send data, where you are only really subscribing to know if it was successful.

```
$paymentResults = NewYorkTimesService.makePayment(paymentJSON); //this does http stuff too.
$paymentResults.subscribe(() => /*I guess it was successful */ , (error)=> /*it failed */);
```

The only thing they share is that they might be of the same called from the same service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of doing it in Angular 5. I think the only thing that may be different between 5 and 6 is where the libraries you are importing come from.

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private backendURL= "http://myurl.endpoint.com/";

  getItems(): Observable<IItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<IItem[]>(backendURL);
  }
  saveItems(items: IItem[]): Observable<IItem[]> {
    let options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})};
    return this.http.post(backendUrl, items, options);
  }
}
```

In your Component class you import the component and subscribe to it.

```
export class ItemComponent {

    itemList: Item[];

    constructor(private itemService: ItemService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

    this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(data => this.itemList = data);

    }  
}
```

Here is a pretty good tutorial that goes over the basics https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: `getItems` in the service is missing a closing brace, and in your `subscribe`, you need `this.itemList` instead of `itemList`

Comment: @user184994 Thanks for pointing it out I fixed it. trying to juggle between C#, Java and Typescript. hah