# How can I populate a static array inside a service from a GET request?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

What I'm trying to do (I think that) is very simple. I'm building a web application and there are some `select` elements that I want to populate with the same data from a remote JSON file (GET request). I created a **service** and I want to populate a static array inside there and call it from any component I want. I think that I miss something which is crucial. 
Here's some code: 
*fetchData.service.ts*

```
export interface Creditor {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class FetchDataService {

    creditorsStaticArray: Creditor[] = [];

    getCreditorsFromAPI() {
        this.http.get<Creditor[]>(this.creditorsUrl)
            .subscribe(
              items => {
                this.creditorsStaticArray = items;
              }
            );
      }

    getCreds() {
        return this.creditorsStaticArray;
    }
}
```

*application-details.component.ts* (one of the components)

```
export class ApplicationDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    loadedCreditors: Creditor[] = [];

    constructor(private fetchDataService: FetchDataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fetchDataService.getCreditorsFromAPI();
        this.loadedCreditors = this.fetchDataService.getCreds();
    }

}
```

My solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51218622)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Handle a callback instead of assignation or try with observables by returning `this.http.get<Creditor[]>(this.creditorsUrl)` and subscribe outer the service

Comment: @FrV As I said below, I implemented all this with observables, but I saw that the ```GET``` request is called for every component that uses this service and I think it will be a performance issue , because I want to have about 10 tabs with a component each.

Comment: I don't think it will be a perfomance issue, if components are not display at the same time : call the service each time is correct. If components are displayed at the same time : make a parent component and share the result of the observable

Comment: @FrV That is an excellent idea! I didn't think of that, and I already have a parent component ;) Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your static array cannot be outside of the scope of your service. However, you cannot really have `static` inside your `class scope` either.

Because `services` in Angular are `singletons` by default, your targeted objective would be achieved by doing something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class FetchDataService {

    creditorsStaticArray: Creditor[] = [];

    getCreditorsFromAPI() {
        this.http.get<Creditor[]>(this.creditorsUrl)
            .subscribe(
              items => {
                this.creditorsStaticArray = items;
              }
            );
      }

    getCreds() {
        return this.creditorsStaticArray;
    }
}
```

As you're already refering to `this.creditorsStaticArray`, this will instantly work. You may want to consider renaming it to `creditorsCache` or something of the like and prevent direct access to it from outside the service (by making it `private`) as it is no longer `static`. But other then naming conventions and access limiters, you're achieving the goal of what you're looking for.

---

Now I'll add some best practices on the bottom here for your future reference.

You're subscribing inside your Service and not managing the subscription "explicitly". This is not necessarily bad, as the default `HttpClient` will complete after a first result, but it may be worth making this more explicit by adding a `.pipe(first())` or `.pipe(take(1))` (`first` is an alias of `take(1)`). This way, if your API or the way you retrieve data changes, there's an explicit reminder that this `Observable` will take 1 value (the entire array) and complete itself, saving the result to a variable as a side-effect.

What you may want to consider is not `subscribing` inside your Service, and returning the entire `Observable` to your components, for it to pass around and decide the moment of subscription. You can still save the state of your variable by putting that in a

```
.pipe(
   tap(data => { this.creditorsCache = data })
)
```

When you or your component (or your HTML by using the `AsyncPipe`) subscribes; it'll store it in its cache and you can handle the new incoming results automatically.

In the example above, you could still rely on your `caching` mechanism as to not hit your server everytime by returning your cached data as an `Observable`. Fortunately RxJS provides plenty of creation `Observables` that this shouldn't be too complex!

A quick example:

```
getCreditorsFromAPI(): Observable<Creditor[]> {
  return this.http.get<Creditor[]>(this.creditorsUrl)
            .pipe(
                tap(data => this.creditorsCache = data)
             )
  );
}

getCreds(): Observable<Creditor[]> {
    // You could also use this to invalidate your cache after 10 minutes!
    if(this.creditorsCache.length > 0) {
        return of(this.creditorsCache)
    }

    // Because I set the return type of this function, you will need to return a valid Observable. This makes your code predictable!
    return this.getCreditorsFromAPI() // This will recreate your cache cause of the tap()!
}
```

In the example above, you would only call `service.getCreds()` and manage the subscription in your component. It'll cache for you automatically everytime you reassign your observable to `this.service.getCreds()`.

Food for thought! I wouldn't say there's a perfect way of doing things and there's definitely more ways that lead to the figurative Rome; but what I just described is definitely a bit more `Reactive` which is what Angular relies on for a lot of its internals.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I had a mistake before (I edited my question), of course I had the 'creditorsStaticArray' inside my class. The thing is that the combobox I want to populate, it's empty :/

Comment: Don't forget that the API call is async aswell, so calling `getCreds` in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook right after the call gets initiated will probably just return an empty array.

Comment: @DanielB Yeah, I think that's my problem. So, when do I have to call ```getCreds``` ?

Comment: Well that's the part of the Reactive programming I added underneath my original basic answer. You could work with `Observables` in your component entirely, so manage the subscription there (by using `asyncPipe` or the like!) and still use your cache. You can easily generate an Observable out of your values by using the `of()` creation operator and send that. It'll be handled like any other Observable so you work using reactive streams. :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how you could rely on your cache without hitting your server all the time.

Comment: @Bjorn'Bjeaurn'S Your example and your insight helped me a lot and I tried to implement your logic into my code. But I run into an issue I think: I added ```console.log()``` inside ```if(this.creditorsCache.length > 0) ``` and I saw that when I call the service from another component, it still does the GET request. Also I tried 2 implementations and I would like to tell me which is more 'correct'. 1. [with Observable](https://pastebin.com/KVjjssqt), 2. [without](https://pastebin.com/kZR61qvx)

Comment: I'll take a look!

Comment: I would recommend going with option 1, with Observable. The `asyncPipe` manages the `subscribe()` for you. It even switches if the reference changes, so when you want to reload your data; you do `this.creditorsObservable = this.fetchDataService.getCreds();` again (you could wrap that in a function) and your HTML will reflect the changes automatically. The manual subscription and management has it places, but this is simple enough! Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: In regards to the `this.creditorsCache.length > 0`, we would have to explore how you provide your service to make sure it's a shared service / singleton throughout the components. If everyone creates its own cache, it's logical that it would hit the server multiple times to build up multiple caches. This seems like a separate question to me though. :-).

Comment: @Bjorn'Bjeaurn'S Thank you so much mate! You helped me understand something that bothered me for 2 days! I'll stick to the ```Observable``` solution and I managed to figure out why the ```this.creditorsCache.length > 0``` was never ```true```. Because it's called 2 times from different components but at the same time, so it had no time to cache the ```creditorsCache```. I feel so stupid :/ Thanks again though!

Comment: Absolutely happy to help! Hit me up if you run into similar or other issues over here or on Twitter or something. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Return Observable from your service :

```
@Injectable()
export class FetchDataService {

    creditorsStaticArray: Creditor[] = [];

    getCreditorsFromAPI() {
        return this.http.get<Creditor[]>(this.creditorsUrl);
      }
}
```

In your component :

```
 loadedCreditors: Creditor[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchDataService.getCreditorsFromAPI()
        .subscribe(res => this.loadedCreditors = res)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly my implementation, but with that approach, I have to call my ```fetchDataService``` every time that I want to populate a ```select``` element. ```creditorsStaticArray``` doesn't used anywhere :/

Comment: You can store the fetched data from API in localStorage and reuse it every time